# NestJS multer not as expected

Tags: express, nestjs, multer

So, when i upload a file with NestJS multer via formdata, its gets the file and uploads it. That part is working, but when a try to set the **destination** to a value from the [formdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrVxw.png), its not working.

When i log the `req.body` it returns `[Object: null prototype]`.

Can you tell me why? Thanks!

**Heres my code:**

```
  @Post("uploadImg")
  @UseInterceptors(
    AnyFilesInterceptor({
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: function (req: any, file, cb) {
          var newAbsoluteDir = "CDN";
          console.log(req.body)
          cb(null, newAbsoluteDir);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + ".png");
        },
      }),
    })
  )
  async uploadedFile(@UploadedFiles() file) {
    console.log(file)
    // console.log(file)
    // return file;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem a little strange to you, but the order of files and data is **important** in this context.

You need to change the order in `form-data` request as well as Postman. First, attach your fields and then attach the files as the last properties.

So you can get your fields from `req.body` in `destination` scope.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks its working now! I even swapped them but i tought it wont work and a swapped it back XD.